# How could I integrate Arachnode.Net web crawler with some of goodness in Searcharoo for a Search Engine Interface?

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

I am currently 70% of finishing my portal in asp.net using C# for a local government agency. The portal is quite big with integration with SQL Server 2008 Analysis, Reporting, and Integration services. Plus, I had successfully deployed and configured it into Windows Server 2008 under Active Directory environment. The next requirement is going to provide a search capability to the portal. The search engine must be able to search contents from the analysis and reporting server as well. For the start, I have made some research on the search engine using Microsoft.Net technology. I am very impressed with the works of experts for Arachnode.Net and Searcharoo. For the time being there is a sample for Arachnode.net to combine with Lucene.Net as complete search engine for asp.net. However, Searcharoo seems better than Lucene.Net for many reasons (in my opinion). Could anyone help me guide briefly on how could I integrate Arachnode.Net and Searcharoo? Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity is there any reason that you are not using the full text search of MS SQL Server 2008 for searching as customizing and maintaining indexes with a search engine (like Lucene or Searcharoo) is a large amount of work.

Comment: Hi Kane, the reason of using Arachnode is that I could do content aggregation by integrating SQL Full Text Search and at the same time crawl the site documents. However, Arachnode.net is a crawler and lack of user interface. It uses Lucene.Net for web interface. What makes Searcharoo has better web interface. It supports for AJAX and Silverlight environment. Besides, Searcharoo indexing capabilities not only support for text, non-text(PDF, Words, Powerpoints), images, and photos but it also  enable geographic coordinates to be indexed; and displaying search results on a map.

Comment: My goal is that I wanted to use commercial Arachnode.net for the intranet site crawler and customize the crawler to add indexing for geographical coordinates (using Searcharoo techniques), analysis cubes, report titles, data mart facts and measures. Due to Google-like highlighting, Searcharoo is a better choice for web interface. I need to integrate Searcharoo with Arachnode.net customized crawler. For more info just go these web addresses: http://arachnode.net/ and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/searcharoo_7.aspx .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find help for setting up Searcharoo spider at my blog post titled

[How do you use Searcharoo library to spider a ASP.NET MVC website](http://draganbl.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-do-you-use-searcharoo-library-to.html)

Comment: Dear Dragan, apologize for my late reply on your answer. I have looked into your blog and I think that also solved on "<Cache xmlns=''> was not expected" error. Thanks a lot for your post. That is going to make me not to use Arachnode coz it is not viable anymore for my problem domain. Searcharoo is powerful enough for internal search. Thanks again for great thinking.